# Multiple mediators, sample size

Tags: sample-size, mediation

I wonder if anybody can help me to get the right answer to a question about mediation (using Process).

I want to test if Difficulties in Emotion Regulation (DERS) is a mediator between other 2 variables.

For Difficulties in Emotion Regulation I can compute a total score (DERS total),and also I can compute a score for each of the six subscales:
1. Non-acceptance of emotional responses (NONACCEPT)
2. Difficulties engaging in goal directed behaviour (GOALS)
3. Impulse control difficulties (IMPULSE)
4. Lack of emotional awareness (AWARE)
5. Limited access to emotion regulation strategies (STRATEGIES)
6. Lack of emotional clarity (CLARITY)

It is right to test the mediator role of the total score and then to test the mediator role for each subscale independently? [in other words, the total score and subscale scores from DERS were independently tested as mediators]

I want to do this to examine which deficit in regulating emotions is more relevant in the investigated association.

It is a problem because the sample size is so small(71)?

Thank you!